# Network manager adds route to vpn host across local network default host

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, networkmanager

I have a wonderful behavior of Network Manager in debian 10,11 xubuntu 20.04.3 when I trying to connect vpn resource by openvpn or l2tp over ipsec.

If I connect openvpn directly across terminal command, it works correctly and there is no strange route even in linux or windows env.

I had this situation across terminal too while I disabled pushing default route to client on server.

But via network manager a have a route like:
 `94.123.223.97 via 192.168.2.1...`
Where `192.168.2.0` is my home subnet

I drew attention to this when i tried to connect vpn tunnel via vpn tunnel. May be it's not a good practice, but I need this in my situation.
So i had two routes with no working connection:

```
94.123.223.97 via 192.168.2.1...
192.168.33.134 via 192.168.2.1...
```

I asked a google by different ways, but not found a solution. Solution with disabling get routes from server doesn't work.

Is it a bug or normal behavior? How can I fix this situation with using tunnel over tunnel?